# How can email-tracking services track emails in Google

Tags: privacy, email, user-tracking, image

Some **email-tracking** services use tracking pixels to detect whether an email was opened. The idea is to add an HTML img tag with an `src attribute` that links to a **1x1** or **0x0** pixel image to the email body. That link uniquely identifies the email.

It looks like this: `https://emailtracker.com/trace/mail/{randome-unique-id}`. So whenever the user clicks the email, the browser will request the tracking URL of the image, which will then trigger and notify the person who sent the email.

After I used one of those services in my Gmail, I opened the inspector to see what the tracking pixel looked like. And to my great astonishment, this is what I found:

[image]

As you can see, the tracking pixel is a **0x0 pixel** image. But its src was changed by Google!

The image was uploaded to Google servers `googleusercontent.com`. The dark part is a part of a long string that identifies the image in the Google servers. Meanwhile, the red part is the URL to the actual image hosted in the servers of the tracking service (the real link). But what is weird is whenever I open the email, I still get a notification that it was opened, even though the request was made to the Google servers!!

I would like to know how the service could detect that the email was opened **even though the src of the tracking pixel was changed, and it points to a server other than theirs**.

**NB: Google changed the src of all the images in the email, so this is not a security protocol to protect from email-tracking services.**

Comment: ... because the Google services contacted the URL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379732/gmail-blocking-pixel-tracking-1x1-pixel-since-today-morning

Comment: Yes @schroeder, I suspected too that the Google serves are acting as proxies and are indexing to actual links, but I was not sure.

Comment: So, I'm not sure this is a security question. Email services will replace links with their own and then test links for issues, You can test this by determining what data is collected by the tracking service when the email is opened. Do you get client info (doubtful) or Google info?

Comment: I understand your point, and since the Google server acts as a proxy, only the Google info (IP address) will be exposed. The security issue that can be debated is the fact of tracking if the email was opened or not, which can be characterized as a problem for the user privacy

Comment: But that's not what you asked. You asked *how* email tracking services can track even though Google re-writes the URL. That's not a security issue. The *impact* may have a security issue, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: The security concern I brought into my question is that I thought that Google was uploading the images to their servers to prevent email tracking and that the tracking service was bypassing this somehow. Until you commented that they are using it as a proxy. Thank you